# Explicit conversion of templated functors to specific functors

Tags: c++, templates, functor, crtp, callable-object

I have a callable struct `Foo` defined as

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T i) const { /* ... */ }
};
```

and for reasons that are out of scope I would like to statically select which type to call it with avoiding the following cumbersome notation:

```
Foo foo;
foo.operator()<int>(0);
foo.operator()<char>('0');
foo.operator()<char>(0);    // Notice: I want to select the implementation 
                            // so that **implicit conversions may take place**.
```

To this end, I'd like to implement a template member function `To()` such that the above can be rewritten as:

```
foo.To<int>()(0);
foo.To<char>()('0');
foo.To<char>()(0);
```

Basically, `foo.To<T>()` would return a callable object that can be used as a callback.
One way to do this can be accomplished by using lambdas:

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T i) const { /* ... */ }

    template <typename T>
    auto To() const {
        return [this](T i) -> void {
            return this->operator()<T>(i);
        };
    }
};
```

However, I don't really like this solution because it creates a lambda and returns it by value, whereas I'd prefer to have some sort of "static cast" of `Foo` that has **no computational overhead compared to a simple call to a member function**. A CRTP solution can also be adopted, but it'd probably add too much boilerplate code for something that I'd expect to be much simpler to be done. **What is the most efficient way to achieve the above objective?**

Comment: How have you established that there's computational overhead? I'd be fairly confident that any non-braindead compiler would optimize it all out.

Comment: Also, not pretty, but `foo.operator()<char>(0);` works.

Comment: The compiler will do this optimization for you, no need to bother with it.

Comment: Also, why not simply do `foo.To<int>(0);` and skip the lambda completely? Are you planning to store the lambda and pass it around before calling it in your real code?

Comment: @Frank @super do you claim that the lambda solution would be as efficient as a normal function call? Isn't there at least an additional layer of indirection with the lambda solution? Should I store the lambda and maybe return it by `const` reference?

Comment: @Frank @super the idea is that I may want to store the functor, or at least use it as a callback in some other functions. That's why I don't need `foo.operator()<char>(0);` and I don't want `foo.To<int>(0);`

Comment: FYI, since your the conversion is done already by the lambda having T as an argument, you can just use `return [this](T i){ return (*this)(i); }` instead of all that casting.

Comment: Demonstration that there's no overhead: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e4nKdW8Kf (more accurate)

Comment: @fdev I've started to suspect that your question's focus might be off. The question states that the main motivation is *"avoiding the following cumbersome notation"*. However, your comments bring up storing something as a callback. The cumbersome notation comes from using a template, but the difficulty in using a non-static member function as a callback is independent of whether or not that member is a template. What is your real question here?

Comment: @Frank you're right, all the casting thing is redundant, and I've edited the question; still, what `return [this](T i){ return (*this)(i); }` as you suggest is wrong because I want to clearly set what instantiation of `operator()` I'll use, so that I can call it also with types `U` different from `T`

Comment: @fdev, look at the resulting assembly from my answer: It calls the correct overload because T has been constrainted. You can play around with it here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jv6ejYn39

Comment: @JaMiT actually I clearly specified that the reasons why I'd like this solution are out of scope, please reread the question. What I asked is what I wrote: is there a more efficient, possibly static way to create a functor templated on a specific type `T`? I naively thought that by returning a lambda by value I'd have incurred some extra computational costs

Comment: @JaMiT I only asked a language-specific question (how can I do this?). If other people for whatever reason want to do the same thing, they may find this question helpful. What bad solution are you referring to? The lambda one seems to be a good solution, and I explicitly asked if there was a better way to achieve the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that there is extra overhead involved is not necessarily correct. Compilers are *really* good at optimizing things, and it's always worth confirming whether that's the case or not before spending time refactoring the code for what will amount to no benefit whatsoever.

Case in point:

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T i) const;

    template <typename T>
    auto To() const {
        return [this](T i) -> void {
            return (*this)(i);
        };
    }
};

// Directly
void foo(const Foo& obj, char v) {
    return obj(v);
}

auto bar(const Foo& obj, int v) {
    return obj.To<char>()(v);
}

// As functors
auto get_foo_functor(const Foo& obj) {
  return obj;
}

auto get_To_functor(const Foo& obj) {
  return obj.To<char>();
}
```

Gcc compiles this down to

```
foo(Foo const&, char):
        movsx   esi, sil
        jmp     void Foo::operator()<char>(char) const
bar(Foo const&, int):
        movsx   esi, sil
        jmp     void Foo::operator()<char>(char) const
get_foo_functor(Foo const&):
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
get_To_functor(Foo const&):
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

You can play around with the example live on godbolt here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jv6ejYn39

Comment: So, basically there's no extra performance cost with the lambda solution, right?

Comment: If that's the case, then you solved my doubt, thanks a lot!

Comment: As long as your compiler is halfway smart and you don't forget to turn on optimizations, then you can be *confident* that there will be no overhead. There are no guarantees here, but then again, there never are when it comes to performance.